# Wordpress MySQL query not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

For some reason the following code isn't working, I am just getting a blank page - I have been pulling my hair out on this one, your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php if ($_GET['id'] >= '1') { 

    $data_entry_id = $_GET['id'];

    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();


    $row_kids = $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM reg_children
                      WHERE children LIKE '%$data_entry_id%'
                      AND uid='$current_user_id'");


     if (!empty($rows_kids)) {

         $wpdb->query("INSERT INTO reg_children VALUES ('' , '$data_entry_id',
         '$current_user_id' )");

     }



}?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Syntax-highlighting alone should solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need like this

```
$row_kids = $wpdb->query("SELECT * FROM reg_children
                          WHERE children LIKE '%$data_entry_id%'
                          AND uid='$current_user_id'");
```

You have meshed with single quotes only and make sure that $wpdb has declared globally.

And also the insert query also should be like

```
$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO reg_children VALUES (NULL , '$data_entry_id',
             '$current_user_id' )");
```

and Mainly your if statement should be like

```
if (!empty($totalRows_kids)) {
```

You forgot closing brace and make sure that you have defined $totalRows_kids...I think that be the count of results from select query

Comment: Ok thanks for your help, I have changed $totalRows_kids to row_kids and have entered your code but still no joy :-(

Comment: Have you changed the closing braces also...??as I mentioned in my ans

Comment: Yes, I have updated the question with the code I am now using

Comment: check your insert query once

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32139/discussion-between-gautam3164-and-james-leist)

Comment: Once see my insert query ,you need to put NULL value for that column

Comment: Thank you so much for your help on this, I have edited the INSERT query but am still getting a blank page...

Answer (score 0):

1. Use double quotes to quote you query. Your string is mistyped.
2. Your `uid` should be number, so no need to type the single quotes also.

Change

```
'SELECT * FROM reg_children WHERE children LIKE '%$data_entry_id%' AND uid='$current_user_id''
```

to:

```
"SELECT * FROM reg_children WHERE children LIKE '%$data_entry_id%' AND uid=$current_user_id";
```

And the insert query should be like the following:

```
"INSERT INTO reg_children VALUES ('' , $data_entry_id, $current_user_id )"
```